# NSOpenPanel Odd Floating Header

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I'm seeing odd NSOpenPanel display in a project. The header column (sort) is floating rather than staying attached to the top of the view. Here is the code I'm using to present the panel:

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
NSArray *fileTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeJPEG, (NSString *)kUTTypePNG, (NSString *)kUTTypeBMP, (NSString *)kUTTypeTIFF];
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
[panel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
NSInteger i = [panel runModal];
```

If I use that same code in a brand new project, it presents correctly. Since I'm presenting a system panel, I don't see how my app could be responsible for this odd display, but I'm open. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I might look for in my app that might be causing this behavior?

[image: Example of floating header]

The app in question is targeting 10.10.

Comment: Why don't you just run a search for NSOpenPanel and get working code?  NSOpenPanel is more than 10 years old and there is nothing new.  If you get something unexpected, then you are doing something unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm pretty sure that the answer you're looking for here is that ultimately you want to use the block based completion handler calling api instead of runModal. apple intentionally or not left the legacy runModal api broken in various ways when it comes to NSOpen/SavePanel and sandboxed applications.

Comment: The problem ended being related to sandboxing, but good call on using the block-based presentation rather than runModal.